# Is there a way to use Pyramid view_config for request_method="HEAD"

Tags: python, pyramid

Pyramid doesn't let you use request_method="HEAD". If there's a request_method="GET" present, that will also process "HEAD" requests:

> As of this release, the request_method view/route predicate, when used, will also imply that HEAD is implied when you use GET. For example, using @view_config(request_method='GET') is equivalent to using @view_config(request_method=('GET', 'HEAD')). Using @view_config(request_method=('GET', 'POST') is equivalent to using @view_config(request_method=('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST'). This is because HEAD is a variant of GET that omits the body, and WebOb has special support to return an empty body when a HEAD is used.

Is there any way to override this behavior?

Comment: I would give a try to `predicates` or `custom_predicates` in view_config. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html#predicate-arguments

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with different code paths for HEAD vs GET? Currently there is no way to override this, but you can for example create your own predicate that does explicit matching on one or the other only. For an example see: https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/config/predicates.py#L33